# How to prevent sorting on click header cell?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I implement column resizing in material table. my problem is the column get sorted.

```
const upFn = () => {
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', moveFn);
    document.removeEventListener('mouseup', upFn);
    this.inMove = false;
    // How to prevent sorting here ?
};
```

Comment: please show html code for `mat-table` you are using

Comment: https://github.com/yantrab/yangular/blob/master/projects/mat-virtual-table/src/lib/table.component.html

Comment: just remove  "|| isResizeActive" from line 17

Comment: do you dont want any sorting or you just want to disable when resizing?

Comment: disable when resizing..

Comment: i updated my answer please try and let me know

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<mat-header-cell
                    #headercell
                    (mousemove)="mousemove($event, i)"
                    (mousedown)="resizeTable($event, i)"
                    fxLayout="row"
                    fxLayoutAlign="space-between stretch"
                    [fxFlex]="column.width"
                    *matHeaderCellDef
                    [disabled]="isResizeActive"
                >
    <div fxFlex [disabled]="column.isSortable === false || isResizeActive" mat-sort-header>
                        {{ column.title || column.field }}
                    </div>
</mat-header-cell>
```

And in your method just set the flag as `true`:

```
const upFn = () => {
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', moveFn);
    document.removeEventListener('mouseup', upFn);
    this.inMove = false;
    this.isResizeActive = true;
};
```

Comment: disable sorting causes style issue...That's why I'm looking for another solution.